# problem with "then" in flutter after update the firebase plugins update

Tags: firebase, flutter

I used this code in the past in my project and it was work perfectly

```
    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.then((user) {
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos').doc().set({
    'body': theController.text,
    'done': false,
    'user_id': user.uid,
    'time': DateTime.now().toString(),
  });
}).then((value) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  theController.clear();
});
```

But now it's Not Accept "`.then`"
the Error is "The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'User"

Comment: check all those 3 duplicates I linked you, `currentUser` is a property now and doesnt return a Future

Answer (score 0):

If you have a read of the [Firebase Auth Changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth/changelog#0180), you will see the following breaking change:

> **BREAKING:** Accessing the current user via currentUser() is now synchronous via the currentUser getter.

Which means it no longer returns a Future, but the user object directly. This means you can simplify your code:

```dart
final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todos').doc().set({
  'body': theController.text,
  'done': false,
  'user_id': user.uid,   'time': DateTime.now().toString(),
}).then((value) {
  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  theController.clear();
});
```